# Web Page Sorting List

Tags: javascript

I'm still a novice at programming. Would like to know how I can make a sorting list for my website.Now by sorting list I mean a list on my website that has a couple of columns and rows, which the user can sort to his preference. here is an example: http://www.rugbyworldcup.com/statistics/season=2011/type=Points/team=0/player=0/statistics/index.html

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You want a sortable table. Check out the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin. It will take a table and make it sortable and a ton of other things, and with only a 1-line config.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, but I have no idea how to use the plug in or to install it. I have too little knowledge about javascript. Any suggestions?